# Find 2nd order transfer function from step response

Tags: transfer-function, step-response

I have to find the tranfer function from the following step response. I would've known how to do this if the system had a steady state. Unfortunately, I don't even know how to begin this task.

[image: Step Rensponse]

I know, that the transfer function is going to look like:

[image: Transfer Function]

Whereas ζ is going to be 0, as the Step Response does not have a steady state.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't have a steady state? I don't think you can say that.

Comment: I thought that as there is no asymptote in the step response diagram, the function has no steady state.

Comment: Hi Lucek. Welcome to StackExchange!

Can you provide more information regarding your graph? Do you have the formula for the step response?

Comment: I don't know the formula, the task is to get it. This is the instruction:
"The figure shows the relevant characteristics of a second order minimal-phase system. Identify the transmittance G (s) of this system by rounding its coefficients to integers."

Comment: If it is minimum phase, then it is stable, and therefore has a steady state. You are being shown only the very early part of the step response. Perhaps you are expected to plot the time-domain step response, and play with the coefficients (using integers, per your comment) until you get something that looks the same for that region of time.

Comment: So ζ is NOT going to be 0? I was thinking about playing with the coefficients but I thought that there is a mathematical way to do it.

Comment: It is not apparent to me whether \$\zeta\$ will or won't be zero. If you go down this path, you could start with it being zero, and see how close you get. Then try to improve by letting it be nonzero. But there could also be a more clever solution than this....it isn't obvious to me.